# Run-time Error 1004 Paste Method of Worksheet Failed (Occur sometime)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating VBA program to copy shape from [Template] Sheet and Paste to [Show] Sheet by using for loop to select and copy&paste.
It's works fine but sometime VBA error [Run-time Error 1004 Paste Method of Worksheet Failed]

This below is my source code

```
Sub createDieProcess(partProcessRowCnt As Integer, dieProcessCD As String, 
    dieProcessPosition As Double, dieProcessWidth As Double)
Dim rShape As Shape
Dim pasteCell As String
    For Each rShape In Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Shapes
        If rShape.Name = dieProcessCD Then
            rShape.Copy
            pasteCell = "P" & partProcessRowCnt
            Range(pasteCell).Select
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Show").Paste 'The record when debug
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 3
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft dieProcessPosition
            Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth dieProcessWidth, msoFalse
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I would appreciate any advice or suggestions. Thanks!

PS I try to use PasteSpecial but it's also showing the same error

Comment: Ok can you please check if activating the worksheet you want to paste your stuff in is active while doing that?

Comment: Thank you for your comment now I'm already fixed the problem
The cause is  `Worksheets("TEMPLATE") ` have too many shape then it loop too many time to find valid shape then I separated into 2 sheet.